# Shallow Heap and Retained Heap are both 0

Tags: android, memory-leaks, eclipse-mat

There are two activities: TestEmptyActivity and FireRoomActivity. 
FireRoomActivity has a button which finishes this activity and starts TestEmptyActivity.
When I run TestEmptyActivity on its own and see the DDMS, I see that Allocated is 12486 MB. But when I start it from FireRoomActivity I see that it is 12530 MB, more than it supposed to be, indicating that there is a memory leak in FireRoomActivity and that gc didn't clear everything when FireRoomActivity is finished. So I open heap dump and search for FireRoomActivity, it finds some instances but as you can see from the screenshot all of them have 0 Retained Heap and 0 Shallow Heap. What could that mean?
 [image]

Answer (score 0):

It means that the class is loaded but there are no instances of it - i.e. the objects column value is 0.